# I need a greater understanding of what a pointer actually points to

Tags: c, pointers

What is the actual value of pointer:

```
char *ptr;
```

And it's pointing to a memory address, correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will try to explain in a simple way, (sorry if my English is not god enough i am learning)
Let say you have an array of characters:

```
char a[5];
```

Then you want to create a pointer to the address of the first element:

```
char *p = &a[0];
```

Now since the name of an array is a synonym for the location of the
initial element you can rewrite to the following statement:

```
char *p = a;
```

Now here is where magic takes place, as the previous character pointer points to the address of the first element you can do stuffs like the following:
instead of getting the 'i'-th element from a[i], you can move the pointer 'i' places to reference the address of the value contained in the 'i'-th position and then get it's value:

`char value = *(a + i);`

Font(The C programming language 2nd Edition, Chapter 5)

Answer (score 2):

Not yet; it's uninitialized.

What you're asking is like asking what number `int i;` refers to.

Answer (score 1):

```
char *ptr;
```

It is not pointing any memory address until it is initialized;
But you can use it to point an address.
Suppose,

```
int i=0;
```

i has an address in memory. if it become `0xFFFF0` then when you write

```
ptr=&i;
```

then your pointer points to address `0xFFFF0` .

now suppose,

`int array[5]={0};` is an array.

then if you write-

```
ptr=array;
```

then `ptr` points to the starting address of array because array name is an address.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is pointing to the address of the variable.

The variable might be on the stack if the variable is declared inside a function, or at the top of RAM if declared at the top level.

As the other answers point out, you haven't made it point to anything yet, so dereferencing the pointer will likely result in a segmentation fault.

You need to do something like

```
char ch;
char *ptr = &ch;
```